# AJAX json returned but wont find values

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, vb.net

I am currently having issues with trying to find values from my returned JSON ajax response.

The ajax code is:

```
$.ajax({
    url         : 'http://zzzzzzzz/Service.asmx',
    type        : 'POST',
    dataType    : 'text',
    contentType : "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\"",
    data        : soapMessage,
    accepts     : 'json: application/json',
    converters  : {"text json": jQuery.parseJSON},
    crossDomain : true,
    error       : function() {
        console.log('An error has occurred');
    },
success     : function(data) {
            $(data).find('febRecordsResult').each(function () {
                var returnedJSON = JSON.parse($(this).text());
                var str = JSON.stringify(returnedJSON, null, 2)

                console.log(str.ReturnedData);
```

The console.log output looks like this:

```
undefined
```

The Json results look like this (**str**):

```
"{\r\n\"ReturnedData\": {\r\n\"howManyLevels\": \"5\",\r\n \"level-1-1-text\": \"test\", 
\r\n \"level-1-1-status\": \"test\", \r\n \"level-1-1-date\": \"4/15/2015\",
\r\n \"level-1-1-dd\": \"50%\", \r\n \"level-1-2-text\": \"test\", 
\r\n \"level-1-2-status\": \"test\", \r\n \"level-1-2-date\": \"4/15/2015\",
\r\n \"level-1-2-dd\": \"25%\", \r\n \"level-1-3-text\": \"test\",    
etc etc....\"\r\n}\r\n}"
```

So why am I not able to pick out **ReturnedData**?

console.log(data) show this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><febRecordsResponse xmlns="http://empDetails.bcbst.com/"><febRecordsResult>"{\r\n\"ReturnedData\": {\r\n\"howManyLevels\": \"5\",\r\n \"level-1-1-text\": \"test\", \r\n \"level-1-1-status\": \"test\", \r\n \"level-1-1-date\": \"4/15/2015\",\r\n \"level-1-1-dd\": \"50%\", \r\n \"level-1-2-text\": \"test\", \r\n \"level-1-2-status\": \"test\", \r\n \"level-1-2-date\": \"4/15/2015\", \r\n \"level-1-2-dd\": \"25%\", \r\n \"level-1-3-text\": \"test\", \r\n \"level-1-3-status\": \"test\", \r\n \"level-1-3-date\": \"4/23/2015\", \r\n \"level-1-3-dd\": \"50%\", \r\n \"level-2-1-text\": \"test\", \r\n \"level-2-1-status\": \"test\", \r\n \"level-2-1-date\": \"4/23/2015\",\r\n \"level-2-1-dd\": \"N/A\", \r\n \"level-2-2-text\": \"test\", \r\n \"level-2-2-status\": \"test\", \r\n \"level-2-2-date\": \"4/8/2015\", \r\n \"level-2-2-dd\": \"N/A\", \r\n \"level-2-3-text\": \"test\", \r\n \"level-2-3-status\": \"test\", \r\n \"level-2-3-date\": \"3/31/2015\", \r\n \"level-2-3-dd\": \"N/A\", \r\n \"level-3-1-text\": \"test\", \r\n \"level-3-1-status\": \"test\", \r\n \"level-3-1-date\": \"4/10/2015\",\r\n \"level-3-1-dd\": \"N/A\", \r\n \"level-3-2-text\": \"test\", \r\n \"level-3-2-status\": \"test\", \r\n \"level-3-2-date\": \"5/1/2015\", \r\n \"level-3-2-dd\": \"50%\", \r\n \"level-3-3-text\": \"test\", \r\n \"level-3-3-status\": \"test\", \r\n \"level-3-3-date\": \"4/18/2015\", \r\n \"level-3-3-dd\": \"N/A\", \r\n \"level-4-1-text\": \"test\", \r\n \"level-4-1-status\": \"test\", \r\n \"level-4-1-date\": \"3/30/2015\",\r\n \"level-4-1-dd\": \"50%\", \r\n \"level-4-2-text\": \"test\", \r\n \"level-4-2-status\": \"test\", \r\n \"level-4-2-date\": \"4/24/2015\", \r\n \"level-4-2-dd\": \"50%\", \r\n \"level-4-3-text\": \"test\", \r\n \"level-4-3-status\": \"test\", \r\n \"level-4-3-date\": \"5/9/2015\", \r\n \"level-4-3-dd\": \"100%\", \r\n \"level-5-1-text\": \"test\", \r\n \"level-5-1-status\": \"test\", \r\n \"level-5-1-date\": \"3/30/2015\",\r\n \"level-5-1-dd\": \"25%\", \r\n \"level-5-2-text\": \"test\", \r\n \"level-5-2-status\": \"test\", \r\n \"level-5-2-date\": \"3/30/2015\", \r\n \"level-5-2-dd\": \"100%\", \r\n \"level-5-3-text\": \"test\", \r\n \"level-5-3-status\": \"test\", \r\n \"level-5-3-date\": \"4/11/2015\", \r\n \"level-5-3-dd\": \"75%\"\r\n}\r\n}"</febRecordsResult></febRecordsResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

After that comes back I use:

```
var returnedJSON = JSON.parse($(this).text());
```

and that makes it look like this:

```
{
"ReturnedData": {
"howManyLevels": "5",
 "level-1-1-text": "test", 
 "level-1-1-status": "test", 
 "level-1-1-date": "4/15/2015",
 "level-1-1-dd": "50%", 
 "level-1-2-text": "test", 
 "level-1-2-status": "test", 
 "level-1-2-date": "4/15/2015", 
 "level-1-2-dd": "25%", 
 "level-1-3-text": "test", 
 "level-1-3-status": "test", 
 "level-1-3-date": "4/23/2015", 
 "level-1-3-dd": "50%", 
 "level-2-1-text": "test", 
 "level-2-1-status": "test", 
 "level-2-1-date": "4/23/2015",
 "level-2-1-dd": "N/A", 
 "level-2-2-text": "test", 
 "level-2-2-status": "test", 
 "level-2-2-date": "4/8/2015", 
 "level-2-2-dd": "N/A", 
 "level-2-3-text": "test", 
 "level-2-3-status": "test", 
 "level-2-3-date": "3/31/2015", 
 "level-2-3-dd": "N/A", 
 "level-3-1-text": "test", 
 "level-3-1-status": "test", 
 "level-3-1-date": "4/10/2015",
 "level-3-1-dd": "N/A", 
 "level-3-2-text": "test", 
 "level-3-2-status": "test", 
 "level-3-2-date": "5/1/2015", 
 "level-3-2-dd": "50%", 
 "level-3-3-text": "test", 
 "level-3-3-status": "test", 
 "level-3-3-date": "4/18/2015", 
 "level-3-3-dd": "N/A", 
 "level-4-1-text": "test", 
 "level-4-1-status": "test", 
 "level-4-1-date": "3/30/2015",
 "level-4-1-dd": "50%", 
 "level-4-2-text": "test", 
 "level-4-2-status": "test", 
 "level-4-2-date": "4/24/2015", 
 "level-4-2-dd": "50%", 
 "level-4-3-text": "test", 
 "level-4-3-status": "test", 
 "level-4-3-date": "5/9/2015", 
 "level-4-3-dd": "100%", 
 "level-5-1-text": "test", 
 "level-5-1-status": "test", 
 "level-5-1-date": "3/30/2015",
 "level-5-1-dd": "25%", 
 "level-5-2-text": "test", 
 "level-5-2-status": "test", 
 "level-5-2-date": "3/30/2015", 
 "level-5-2-dd": "100%", 
 "level-5-3-text": "test", 
 "level-5-3-status": "test", 
 "level-5-3-date": "4/11/2015", 
 "level-5-3-dd": "75%"
}
}
```

But still when I got to choose **ReturnedData** its still says *undefined*.

```
console.log(returnedJSON.ReturnedData);
```

and

```
console.log(returnedJSON['ReturnedData']);
```

Comment: What do you get if you log just `data` to the console. It looks like it should be a javascript object as it's already parsed, and how do you get `text()` from that, and parse it again ?

Comment: Also, `str` is clearly a string, it doesn't have a `ReturnedData` property ?

Comment: It looks to me like you are treating your JSON like the DOM.  `find` is a DOM method.  Also `febRecordsResult` is not a valid selector for it.

Comment: Just updated my code in my OP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to do the following to get it to find the value:

```
$(data).find('febRecordsResult').each(function (dataa) {
    var returnedJSON = JSON.parse($(this).text());

    returnedJSON = returnedJSON.ReturnedData[0];
    $('#howManyRecs').append(returnedJSON.howManyLevels);
    $('#level1text').append(returnedJSON['level-1-1-text']);
    $('#level1status').append(returnedJSON['level-1-1-status']);
    $('#level1date').append(returnedJSON['level-1-1-date']);
    $('#level1dd').append(returnedJSON['level-1-1-dd']);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your returned values are through `data.d`.

Comment: data.d comes up as *undefined*

Comment: You need to take another look at your ajax request... Datetype is wrong if you are expecting JSON... I have always used data.d and I have never ran into issue's. Change the datatype and use a console.log to find out what is going on. Also should be using the f12 developer tools to find out what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't dataType = json? If not console.log(str) and view the object and take a look at the values it's returned.

Comment: If i do that then my call to the SOAP does not work.

Comment: Can't you use data type 'XML'  and convert your XML to json with something like ... http://davidwalsh.name/convert-xml-json